# setTimeout wait to execute what's after

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to know how to make setTimeout wait before executing what comes after.

```js
setTimeout( function() { console.log("First"); }, 5000 );
console.log("Second");
```

In the console I want to see:
First
Second

"First" after 5 seconds and then "Second" just after "First"
But what's really happening is that I have "Second" and after 5 seconds "First"

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 4):

If [IE is not priority](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) and you allowed to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), then you can use a simple `wait` function to work as `setTimeout` and return `Promise`which allows for [method chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining):

```js
function wait(t) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       window.setTimeout(resolve, t)
   });
}

wait(5000)
.then(function(){ console.log("First"); })
.then(function(){ console.log("Second"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout( function() { console.log("First"); }, 1000 );
setTimeout( function() { console.log("Second"); }, 1000 );
```

Comment: @Simo03 If you choose to be mysterious about why "It can't be inside" - I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not guarantee linear order of execution in your code. You can't expect your code to execute line by line when introducing timeouts or asynchronous tasks.

You could print both lines within the resolving function:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("First");
  console.log("Second");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: js does guarantee, that `console.log("Second");` will run before `console.log("First");` in OP's code

Comment: And it is my understanding that OP does not want that to happen... Having the second line of your code executed before the first line is non-linear. I do not see the point of your comment and downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to make setTimeout wait before executing what comes after.

I think the JavaScript function for "wait" is `setTimeout`. Meaning you can achieve this by nesting one `setTimeout` function inside another.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Second');
  }, 100);
  console.log('First');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The second one is not really a console.log (I have another pieace of code) It can't be inside setTimeout

Comment: Well the code in your question says it can. Please update the question to show the kind of code  which can't be inside setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing more than just a console log after, you can write a new function to run after the setTimeout. Anything in the "second" function will occur after logging "First".

```
var second = function () {
    console.log("Second");
}

setTimeout( function() { 
    console.log("First");
    second();
}, 5000 );
```